# mail-listener-next produces openssl error

Tags: node.js, email, openssl

I am attempting to listen to a specific email inbox using mail listener next.

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener-next");

var mailListener = new MailListener({
  username: "user",
  password: "pass",
  host: "host",
  port: 143, // imap port
  tls: true,
  connTimeout: 10000, // Default by node-imap
  authTimeout: 5000, // Default by node-imap,
  debug: console.log, // Or your custom function with only one incoming argument. Default: null
  tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
  mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
  fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
  mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
  attachments: false, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
  //attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" }, // specify a download directory for attachments
  // to make server respond to other requests you may want
  // to pause for 'fetchingPauseTime' fetching of the email, because it 'hangs' your app
  fetchingPauseThreshold: null, // amount bytes
  fetchingPauseTime: 5000 // ms to pause fetching and process other requests
});

mailListener.start(); // start listening to the box

mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
  console.log("imapConnected");
});

mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
  console.log("imapDisconnected");
});

mailListener.on("error", function(err){
  console.log(err);
});

mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment, email) {
    if(attachment.includes(".pdf")) {
        // do whatever here
        console.log("message received. Executing shell script");
    }
});
```

Please note that I put dummy values for `username`, `password`, and `host`.
I am receiving this error message.

```
[connection] Error: Error: 47043870756864:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

{ Error: 47043870756864:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

    at Socket.ondata (internal/js_stream_socket.js:64:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:197:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:17) source: 'socket' }
[connection] Closed
imapDisconnected
```

So far, I have verified that the username, password, host, and port are all correct. Openssl is running on version 1.0.1f. I've also made sure the dependencies for mail listener next are installed and updated. At this point, I'm sure there's an issue with the code itself, but I'm not seeing it. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The "wrong version number" error from openssl means that the maximum SSL/TLS version supported by the server has been disabled by the client.  If you haven't disabled versions yourself, then there are a number of older (considered unsecure now) versions.

I would suggest that you upgrade supported TLS versions supported on the server (or ask them to).

If you really need to connect to this server, then you should be able to connect to the server you can enable the older versions of ssl / tls until it works.

You can use openssl [s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-s_client.html) to test the connect to see what version you need to enable.

The options you want to play with are:

> -ssl2, -ssl3, -tls1, -tls1_1, -tls1_2, -no_ssl2, -no_ssl3, -no_tls1, -no_tls1_1, -no_tls1_2 These options require or disable the use of the specified SSL or TLS protocols. By default the initial handshake uses
>   a version-flexible method which will negotiate the highest mutually
>   supported protocol version.

e.g.

> openssl s_client -tls1 -connect www.site.com:443

Comment: When I try to use the tool, I get this error: `47849068959520:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:795:` Should I be entering a username and password with this?

Comment: No, at this point there is no username / password to use.  It's just testing the ssl stream setup.  My guess is that your version of openssl is too new.  If you run "openssl version" and it's greater than 1.0.x then the older protocol types have been completely removed.  You may need to figure out how to enable the older protocols in your code setup.  Or get the server updated to a newer version of openssl (or whatever ssl socket library it's using) to support newer tls protocol versions.